# Regarding copy constructor and NRVO

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, nrvo

```
class Date
{
private:
int day,month,year;
public:
Date (int d,int m,int y)
{
day=d;
month=m;
year=y;
}
Date (Date &d)
{ 
day=d.day;
month=d.month;
year=d.year;
}
int monthDays(int month,int year)
{
    if((year%4)==0){
    if(month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11){
        return 30;
    }
    else
    if(month==2){
        return 29;
    }
    else
        return 31;
    }
    else{
        if(month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11){
            return 30;
        }
        else
        if(month==2){
            return 28;
        }
        else
        return 31;
    }
}
Date operator+ (const int k) 
{
    Date copy(day,month,year);
    int inc_days=k;
  if(inc_days<=(monthDays(copy.month,copy.year)-copy.day)){
        copy.day+=inc_days;
        return copy;
    }
    else{
        inc_days-=(monthDays(copy.month,copy.year)-copy.day);
        copy.day=monthDays(copy.month,copy.year);
        while(inc_days>0){
            copy.year+=(copy.month/12);
            copy.month+=1-12*(copy.month/12);
            if(inc_days>monthDays(copy.month,copy.year)){
                copy.day=monthDays(copy.month,copy.year);
                inc_days-=monthDays(copy.month,copy.year);
            }
            else{
                copy.day=inc_days;
                inc_days=0;
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }     
}
};
int main()
{
Date d1(2,3,2004); //uses another constructor //line 1
Date d3(d1); //line 2
Date d2=d1+2; //uses overloaded + operator //line 3
}
```

Even though line 2 does not take a temporary object as an argument I am still getting a compiler error if I don't add a const in the copy constructor argument. 
In case of line 3 , the overloaded operator returns an object using NRVO .So it should not use the copy constructor. But it still gives a compiler error. Both these errors vanish if I add a const in the copy constructor argument.But why should it give an error?

Comment: What is `Date`? The declaration might be involved in this error. The exact error would also be helpful.

Comment: Please show an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Date is a class I created with 3 private variable day,month and year.

Comment: Show your code.  We don't want to guess what you've typed.  A single character can change the meaning of C++ code.

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question and add the rest of the code.

Comment: @CodeMaxx - How could this code have compiled if your `Date` constructors are all `private`?  If not, please post the *real* code, not hastily typed in code.

Comment: That code has many errors in it.  But after I fixed it up I can get line 1 and line 2 to compile fine.  That's without the const on the copy constructor.  Using both gcc and visual studio.

Comment: Sorry about the errors . I had been copying from a multiple file code.
yes it worked for line 1 and line 2 without const. what about line 3?

Comment: @CodeMaxx Neil Kirk answers that part of your question below.

Comment: @AnonMail  Yes he did....Appreciate your help.Thanxx

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry for the mistyped code.I made the corrections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the copy constructor is optimized out by the compiler, the code must still compile correctly as if the copy constructor were theoretically called. You need to make the parameter to the copy constructor a const reference in order to take a temporary object.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why a theoretical call should also go through ? Does in make any difference in any special case?

Comment: @CodeMaxx It is a safety mechanism. If the class doesn't provide a safe way to copy itself, then returning it by value if disabled, even if the compiler can optimize out the copies.